# How to remove last letter of string from list? Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi guys I'm trying to remove or hide the last letter from List

Any possible ways?

```
Text(list[i].name,
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color:
              list[i].isBook == "0"
                  ? selectedTimingSlot[i] ? WHITE : BLACK
                  : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              fontSize: 15,
          ),
        ),
```

`**Above code shows= "12:00 AM" I need to hide or remove "AM"**`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substring` method:

```
main() {
  print("12:00 AM".substring(0,5));
}
```

Or with `replaceAll` method:

```
main() {
  print("12:00 AM".replaceAll("AM","").replaceAll("PM",""));
}
```

with regular expression:

```
main() {
  var regex = new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]');
  print("02:00 AM".replaceAll(regex,""));
}
```

Comment: Dude,Thank you! Works like a charm <3

Comment: Welcome, do consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ketan’s substring method is a terrible way of doing this, what about “9:00 PM”?

Edit: looks like his method worked perfectly!

Use regex and/or the following package:

https://pub.dev/packages/string_validator

Comment: I thought about it, but mostly time is formatted like "09:00" so it works.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is with this extension

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String deleteLastChar({int toDelete = 1}) => substring(0, length - toDelete);
}
```

And you can use like

```
"12:00 AM".deleteLastChar(toDelete: 3) // Prints 12:00
```

Why `toDelete: 3`? Because you also want to remove the space between `12:00` and `AM`